# Create new array field with values from object field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Given that in my db I have objects like this:

```
_id: 1,
class: 'x',
urls: {
  'a': '/someAUrl',
  'b': '/someBUrl'
}
```

I would like to run a script that transforms those objects to:

```
_id: 1,
class: 'x',
urls: {
  'a': '/someAUrl'
},
urls2: [
  {type:'a', url:'/someAUrl'}
]
```

The initial *urls* field must remain. I tried running something like this inside mongo shell with no success:

```
db.eval(db.test.find({ class: 'x' }).snapshot().forEach(   function (e) {     e.urls2 = [{ url: e.urls.a, type: 'a'}];     db.test.save(e);   } ))
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate the data in the collection?

Comment: Probably it is a typo.

Comment: @superciccio14 yeap, needed to pass a function to eval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to pass a function to db.eval, like this:

```
db.eval(function() {db.test.find({ class: 'x' }).snapshot().forEach(   function (e) {     e.urls2 = [{ url: e.urls.a, type: 'a'}];     db.test.save(e);   } )})
```

and it worked